# Cassandra-i able to connect via sudo command but unable to connect via cqlsh

Tags: linux, cassandra

i am trying to run below command

```
#!/bin/bash 
cqlsh -u usename -p password -e "SELECT * from poh.ne_q_iam;"
```

but m getting below error

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': Connection Shutdown('Connection <Asyncore Connection(140545783069776) 127.0.0.1:9042 (closed)> is already closed',)})
```

but when i try to run via sudo its working

```
sudo -u casadm cqlsh node-1 -u cassandra -p 3D4TMobile@ --ssl
```

what will be cqlsh equivalent of above sudo command

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the node is listening only on specific interface, and not on the localhost (127.0.0.1). You just need to add `node-1` to the `cqlsh` command:

```
cqlsh -u usename -p password -e "SELECT * from poh.ne_q_iam;" node-1
```